# Web helpers for MVC 5?

Tags: html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5

is there any documentation for Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers for ASP.NET MVC 5?

I'm trying to use `FileUpload` helper and run out of ideas..

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
```

tried to put this line on top of my View and few other variations...

Comment: I don't think there is any official documentation as they have not made to the BCL yet. And I guess you downloaded from Nuget. Why not open the assembly using Reflector, or any decompiler and see what's available for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

I never find documentation for all the helpers. There is no helper for the file upload.

Use  and don't forget to use POST and set enctype = "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score -2):

You can use Microsoft.Web.Helpers.